# Adding diodes to easy driver stepper motor driver

Tags: schematics, stepper-motor, wiring

I had an easy motor driver damaged by removing the motor while the drive was energized. I sent an email to Brian Shmalz to see if there was anything that could be done to protect the board in these cases. He replied with the following:

> You can add eight diodes to the four motor lines (one diode to M+ and one to GND for each of the four lines) to help protect the driver in case a user removes the motor while under power.

and

> You'll want Schottkey diodes with a nice low forward voltage - like 400mV or so at 1.5A or so.

I ordered some of the diodes he recommended however I am still learning when it comes to electronics like this and I don't really understand what he is advising to do.

The board has 4 motor pins in a set of A/B pairs. I don't understand where the 8 diodes should be placed in relation to these pins, or which orientation the + and - sides of the diodes should be in. Schematics and diagrams can be found here http://www.schmalzhaus.com/EasyDriver/

How should this be wired to accomplish what Mr. Schmalz has suggested?

Comment: This might help, it is a schematic of an [H Bridge](http://www.robotroom.com/BipolarHBridge.html) a motor is in the centre, and the 4 diodes on either side (ignore the components outside those, your Easy Driver is doing their job). The motor in that diagram has one coil, two connections. A stepper motor has two coils, and hence 4 connections, and so you need to connect the diodes in the same pattern to its second coil. If a motor connection gets more negative than ground, diode D2 or D4 conducts, if higher than +M (+9.6V) D1 or D3 is conducts, so motor connections stay within 0 and +M, +/-0.4V

Comment: @gbulmer Thank you, I sort of understand. Is there an "explain to a 5 year old" version of that?

Comment: It is important, and widely used, but I haven't found a simpler version yet. I have found even more complex ones. A motor is both a generator of electricity, and an inductor, which stores energy in its magnetic field. In both cases they will try to supply electrical energy when power is removed (by disconnecting a wire from the motor). If that energy is fed back into the motor drive chip (which is a two H-Bridges) on wire which is still connected, the motor will tend to pull the motor drive connection above M+ or below GND, and destroy is. The diodes conduct that power to M+ or GND instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The diodes are meant for absorbing voltage spikes above M+ and below GND. They have to have low voltage drop to start conducting sooner then the built-in diodes. As the message says, they have to be connected between output and power rails, like this (ignore the depicted buffer):

[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [radio-electronics.com](http://www.radio-electronics.com/images/esd-protection-diodes-circuit.gif))</sub>

**Edit**: The diodes should be wired like this:

[image: pic2]

Comment: I'm sorry, like I said I am still learning. I don't understand what this diagram means exactly. How does this relate to the two pair motor pins on the driver board? I can see how you would put a diode between each of the pins and the motor, but that's only 4 not 8 so I know I am deeply misunderstanding something critical here.

Comment: Ignore that triangle in the middle.  The center line is one of your (4) motor lines.  The line marked "Rail" is M+ (which I assume is the positive supply rail of the controller.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I follow you so far, but there is no separate ground wire just the two pairs. Where does the second diode go? So sorry for being dense here, I'm used to working in software side of things not the electronics.

Comment: @asawyer There are indeed no separate wires, you have to attach the diodes between solder joints at motor connector and solder joints at power connector. Leads of leaded diodes should be long enough to do it without extension wires. From every motor terminal, one diode goes to M+ and one to GND.

Comment: @venny I think I understand what your saying, I'm not quite sure still how to translate that into an actual real life circuit. For the M+ the diode just sits between the board and the motor (right?), but how is the GND wired? I am not seeing in the diargram of the board where to place the diode exactly... Once again sorry for the dumb questions. I am trying.

Comment: @venny that is so helpful, thank you so so so much

Comment: @venny With your diagram everything everyone was trying to tell me suddenly makes sense